# laravel excel download and parse file from URL

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [Laravel excel package](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel) version 2 and want to download an excel file **from a given URL**.
The function `Excel::download` was added in version 3. is there any way to still download excel files in version 2? maybe using  `file_get_contents()` function from PHP itself.

Comment: You already had an idea. Did you try it? What is the result? Show us some code.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#downloading-files

Answer (score 2):

From the Maatwebsite/Excel documentation:

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {

    })->export('xls');

    // or
    ->download('xls');
```

https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/export/export.html